# CSS responsive img downscale by width and height

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, height, liquid

I have been trying to migrate my current website layout to an responsive one but I faced the following problem. In my image gallery I output thumbnails in liquid columns depending on the viewport. I use media queries to achieve that for the different viewports and always use width as percentage of the screen width. I have both horizontal and vertical oriented thumbnails. Scaling down works good but at certain point, when the images start to scale down, the vertical images are becoming larger than the horizontal ones and overflow their parent elements. This being said I am looking for a way to constrain downscaling by both width and height. For example if I use width: 16%; height: 0; padding-bottom: 16%; to achieve square element a would like to constrain the img within that element to scale accordingly when its height becomes equal to the parent element height.

Is there a CSS only solution to that problem?

Here is my code:

```css
.photo-list {
 padding: 45px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.photo-thumb {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
    padding-bottom: 16%;
    width: 16%;
    height: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: grey;
    }

.photo-thumb img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1440px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 1440px){
    .photo-thumb {
    width: 21%;
    padding-bottom: 21%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1080px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 1080px){
    .photo-thumb {
    width: 29.3333%;
    padding-bottom: 29.3333%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 530px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 530px){
    .photo-thumb {
    width: 46%;
    padding-bottom: 46%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 320px){
    .photo-thumb {
    width: 96%;
    padding-bottom: 96%;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="photo-list clear">
    <li class="photo-thumb">
        <img alt="somewhere far beyond" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/nature/">
    </li>
    <li class="photo-thumb">
        <img alt="into the wild" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/city/">
    </li>
    <li class="photo-thumb">
        <img alt="missing summer" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/sports/">
    </li>
    <li class="photo-thumb">
        <img alt="light trails" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/business/">
    </li>
    <li class="photo-thumb">
        <img alt="living tree" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/fashion/">
    </li>
    <li class="photo-thumb">
        <img alt="end of day" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/nature/">
    </li>
    <li class="photo-thumb">
        <img alt="ray of light" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/city/">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers,
Jerome

Comment: Your snippet is not working, please use absolute paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might solve your problem. In this snippet I considered that you can assign 'vertical' and 'horizontal' class to your images as per the nature of image. If you don't know which image is going to be vertical and horizontal then you have to use a little js there to assign classes depending on naturalHeight and naturalWidth of image.

```css
.photo-list {
 padding: 45px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.photo-thumb {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
    padding-bottom: 16%;
    width: 16%;
    height: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    }
.thumb-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.photo-thumb img {
    position: relative;
}
.photo-thumb img.vertical {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
.photo-thumb img.horizontal {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1440px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 1440px){
    .photo-thumb {
    width: 21%;
    padding-bottom: 21%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1080px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 1080px){
    .photo-thumb {
    width: 29.3333%;
    padding-bottom: 29.3333%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 530px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 530px){
    .photo-thumb {
    width: 46%;
    padding-bottom: 46%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 320px){
    .photo-thumb {
    width: 96%;
    padding-bottom: 96%;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="photo-list clear">
    <li class="photo-thumb">
        <div class="thumb-container">
            <img class="horizontal" alt="somewhere far beyond" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="photo-thumb">
        <div class="thumb-container">
            <img class="horizontal" alt="into the wild" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="photo-thumb">
        <div class="thumb-container">
            <img class="vertical" alt="missing summer" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/sports/">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="photo-thumb">
        <div class="thumb-container">
            <img class="vertical" alt="light trails" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/sports/">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="photo-thumb">
        <div class="thumb-container">
            <img class="horizontal" alt="living tree" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="photo-thumb">
        <div class="thumb-container">
            <img class="horizontal" alt="end of day" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="photo-thumb">
        <div class="thumb-container">
            <img class="vertical" alt="ray of light" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/sports/">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Akash and thank you for your answer! I have added the orientation as a class in the backend and it works fine. I was also wondering since I have to add <a href> and a <span> including the title for each thumbnail what would be a good approach to do so in order to keep the margin between the list containers preventing the span to bleed over the next element in the column if the span is too long?

Comment: this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phoenix4rmhell/ye22j4xx/) shows a  way to add caption to each image. You can add as long captions as you like. I copied the code from answer snippet and didn't edit it just in case you don't like this way.

Comment: Thank you again Akash, unfortunately the problem with this approach is that since the caption is outside parent and thumb containers the caption is showed too far away for horizontal thumbnails. Is there a way I can show the caption with the same distance below the thumbnail for both vertical and horizontal thumbnails and still force the responsive margin to take the caption presence in account while adjusting, preventing it from overlapping with other parts of the list?

Comment: Hi @JeromeWalters, I won't say this is the best approach out there. This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ye22j4xx/1/) shows how you can keep the captions near the horizontal images. The `<li>` will still occupy the caption space even if (caption + image) height < parent-container height. No JS is used in this version. If we can use some JS then we can get better results to keep `<li>` height as less as we can.

Comment: here's another [VERSION](http://jsfiddle.net/ye22j4xx/2/) with JS code to make everything look just like you wanted..

Comment: Akash, thanks. Maybe this [way](http://jsfiddle.net/ye22j4xx/4/) is a little bit better, first the thumb being clickable, second I removed the condition for the height adjustment from the JS in order to work for horizontal thumbs keeping the space after them the same as the space after vertical ones. Isn't the adjustHeight(); within the .ready() supposed to adjust the height when the page is loaded? On my page when it is loaded the thumbs get screwed flowing over each other until the page is resized.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem with the thumbs flowing over each other on load updated version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ye22j4xx/6/). Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: "Isn't the adjustHeight(); within the .ready() supposed to adjust the height when the page is loaded?"

It'll adjust height once the document is ready. The images are loaded after $(document).ready() is fired. So binding the adjustHeight() with $(window).load() will work as you've used in your second example.

Good Job!